# Checking Session to direct to relevant page

Tags: php

I would like to know if anyone can help me with this $_SESSION variable problem. I want to add a script to a signup page that will allow someone that is already logged in to access the page from the backend and for someone who is not logged in to be redirected to the index page. Currently what is happening is that the page, when accessed from outside is redirected to index which is perfect, but from within the backend, when clicked on add user, it stays on the same page. Please excuse all the mistakes = still very new to PHP.

```
require 'function.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) && !empty($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
header('Location: ../../scripts/backend_login/signup.php');
} else {
header('Location: ../../scripts/backend_login/index.php');
}
```

Comment: add `session_start()` before the if condition.

Comment: @ Midhun MP: Thank you for prompt reply! I added the code as suggested by you (edited code above), and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: ok, Is the locations are correct ? Because in your condition if the user authenticated will go to signup page and the user who is not registered will go to index page, is that correct ?

Comment: @ Midhun MP: Yes the locations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by ensuring you have a session_start() on every page needing the session variable.

Next, change your code to this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) {
     if ($_SESSION['authenticated'] == true) {
     header('Location: ../../backend_login/index.php');
} else {        
     header('Location: ../../backend_login/signup.php');
}
}
```

Try that and see

The true will only work if that is the value of the authenticated session

----EDIT----

The ($_SESSION['authenticated'] == true) is not vital, it is just another fail-safe to be double sure the correct session state is active, can be completed without this

Comment: Howzit Lemuel! Thanks for your input. The strangest thing is happening, when I insert your code, it gives me an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file. In Aptana 3 I am not seeing any syntax errors in your code only a syntax error at the end of the file. But when i take your code out - it got no errors. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, end of file sorted. Now when I am in admin - it goes to the signup page, but when not logged in and in the browser manually typing the url - it goes to the signup page and not index. ive tried swopping the two headers, but it does the same thing regardless.

Comment: Made an edit that fixes eof error, to test your code, put echos in your if statement to test which condition is being met. Because switching the headers should work

Comment: Thank you Lemuel. I tried your advice, but the error remains the same. Do you think it can be because if one is trying to access the signup page from admin, that its not sure what to do with the isset statement? because if i make it !isset with FALSE, the signup page can not be accessed from outside - what I want - but also not accessible from admin.

Comment: You can wrap that if-statement in another if-statement to check whether or not the user is an administrator

Answer (score 0):

You should start your session on every page where you use $_SESSION

session_start() 
before the rest of your code

Comment: @ Gert B: Hi Gert B, Thank you for your answer. When I do that, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem. Here is the solution.

```
require_once('function.php');
session_start();

if (!is_user()) {
redirect('index.php');
}
```

thank you all for helping!